# Any other possible reasons for "Not enough quota" from PostMessage?

Tags: windows, multithreading, window, message-queue, postmessage

When posting a Windows message from a worker thread back to the main thread, our process sporadically receives the "not enough quota" error. Problem is that through extensive tracing we are now quite sure that the main thread's message queue is empty.

This is the configuration:
Regular Windows process, no GUI, hidden main window.
Worker thread creates its own window and message loop.
The two are exchanging messages via PostMessage from time to time. Frequency is in the order of one message per couple of seconds.

I couldn't find any other possible reason for this error in the net than the message queue being filled with 10.000 messages, but as I said, we are quite sure that this is not the case. Are there any other known situations, where this error code can be returned from a PostMessage call?

Comment: Never seen anything like that in decades of PostMessaging :(

Comment: Could perhaps be some other software on the system interfering.  Have you tried running your code on a vanilla test machine?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: No, and that's not easy too because the process is part of quite a big system. However, how can other processes possibly interfere with my message loop?

Comment: Only via DLL injection or hooking, AFAIK, but that's sadly more common than you might expect.  Security software would be the most likely suspect if this is the cause.  I don't suppose you have any way of predicting that a particular PostMessage call will fail before you make it?  For example, once it starts failing, does it then do so consistently?

Comment: Long shot, but it might be talking about your working set quota.  Try using `SetProcessWorkingSetSize` to increase it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes, we never observed it coming back to work after the failure. And sure, we will try the working set quota, I am running out of ideas anyway ;-)

Comment: So, have you tried stepping into the PostMessage call in the debugger to see if there are any hints as to the cause of failure?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: We have now tried everything with no success. It has been decided to implement now a redesign that was planned for some time and eliminates the message queues. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I wanted to share with you, what we finally found as the reason for the behavior: Without our knowledge one of the libraries the process uses has added a new window to the main thread and creates a lot of messages for it. So its more or less what you guessed in your first comment :)) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KitFisto I am experiencing the same problem, how did you validate the messaqe queue size?